# JS счётчик

Tags: javascript

Есть определенное положительное число.
Нужно рандомно каждые 5-15 секунд плюсовать к нему случайно 1-5 и выводить на экран. При обновлении страницы счётчик сбрасывается.
Подскажите как реализовать, понимаю, что элементарщина, но в js вообще не разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var my_var = 2312312;

var lock = false;
window.setInterval(function() {
  if(!lock) {
    lock = true;
    var delay = Math.random()*10000+5000;
    var id = window.setInterval(function() {
      my_var += Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;
      console.log(my_var);
      window.clearInterval(id);
      lock = false;
    }, delay);
  }
}, 5000);
```